# Binding spinner with data retrieved from wcf web service

Tags: wcf, web-services, xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am using a simple wcf web service in my Xamarin android application. I have GetAllUser function to retrieve all users from database.

I am able to insert users using my Xamarin android application.
But i am clueless about how to bind the data retrieved from web services with spinner control in my Xamarin android.
I have searched many places on internet but i have still no way of binding my spinner with web service.

```
namespace WcfServiceSunday
{
    public class ServiceSunday : IServiceSunday
    {

        public  List<Employee> GetAllEmployee()
        {
            List<Employee> employee = new List<Employee>();
            string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            con.Open();
            string qry = "select * from EmpDetail";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Employee emp = new Employee();
                emp.EmpNo = dr.GetInt32(0);
                emp.Name = dr.GetString(1);
                emp.Empcode = dr.GetString(2);
                emp.keywords = dr.GetString(3);
                emp.mobile = dr.GetString(4);

                employee.Add(emp);

            }
            con.Close();
            return employee;

        }
```

Above is my web service for selecting all users from database.
I want to bind spinner and show user names in my spinner control.

Following is my button click event to populate the spinner.

```
 btn.Click += (sender, e) => {

                Employee emp = new Employee();
                GridView grdvw = FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.grd);

                IList<Employee> employ = new List<Employee>();
                employ = sc.GetAllEmployee("");
                Spinner sp = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);

                sp.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem ,employ.ToList());

            };
```

I am able to populate the spinner with web service but the data displayed in the spineer
is like:

```
"WcfServiceSunday.Employee"
```

I am getting this above as values in mthe spinner drop down instead of names of the users
in my database.

How to populate the spinner with the names of users??

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind it unless you use something like MvvmCross or QuickCross for data binding. However as always with Android you have to create an `Adapter` to fill a `View`, such as `ListView`, `Spinner` or `GridView` with content. This is fairly easy and trivial to do:

```
public class MySpinnerAdapter : ArrayAdapter<Employee>
{
    private readonly int _resource;
    private readonly int _resourceId;

    public MySpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, IList<Employee> objects)
        : base(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects)
    {
        _resource = resource;
        _resourceId = textViewResourceId;
    }

    public override View GetDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var inflater = LayoutInflater.FromContext(Context);
        var view = convertView ?? inflater.Inflate(_resource, parent, false);
        var textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(_resourceId);
        textView.Text = GetItem(position).Name;
        return view;
    }
}
```

spinneritem.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerText"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:color="#ffffff" />
```

So with the code above you can populate your Spinner with the following simple code snippet:

```
var spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);
spinner.Adapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.spinneritem, Resource.Id.spinnerText, _serviceSunday.GetAllEmployee());
spinner.ItemSelected += (s, e) => 
{
    //Do something with the selected item
    //get the position with e.Position
}
```

Given that `_serviceSunday` is an instance of your `ServiceSunday` class.

You can of course customize the spinner item to your liking, add more information to it etc. just remember to reflect those changes in the `Adapter`.

Comment: I have edited my code and posted again. I want to populate my spinner with names of users in my database.But i am seeing the items of spinner as "WcfServiceSunday.Employee".

Comment: This is probably due to you assigning the entire `Employee` object, rather than its `Name` property, to the `TextView`. See my edited answer, or provide more information on what you did to fix the small copy/paste error I introduced in the `Text` property assignment in `GetDropDownView`.

Comment: I have not tried your code yet. I will definately try it. I want to know how to select each names from the "WcfServiceSunday.Employee" using my code. Because I have used the same code to bind my dropdownlist in a web page. Dropdownlist have "datavaluefield" and "datatextfield" assigning them what value to fetch from database they work. How can this be done in spinner?

Comment: If spinner can populate "WcfServiceSunday.Employee" in their list of items then there should be a way to make them display a particular value instead of whole Employee object? Waiting for your answer

Comment: Cheesebaron thanks for your yes ;) finally i solved it finally without using loop. Simply iterated through my whole list using where query. Thanks for your effort.